# Python: Print just once in raw_function

Tags: python

```
result = raw_input("Enter results file: ")

while True:
    try:
        result = get_marks_from_file(result)
        break
    except IOError:
        print 'Please supply correct file. '
```

Above is the `raw_input` function that I am using to bring a file. When I put correct file name, it works well. But when I put something else such as `'asdsada'`, the sentence `'please supply correct file. '` is printed and it doesn't stop. Is there any method for just one printing and return to the question?

Any advices or helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `raw_input` inside your loop:

```
while True:
     result = raw_input("Enter results file: ")

     try:
         result = get_marks_from_file(result)
         break
     except IOError:
         print 'Please supply correct file. '
```